# EF7 reverse engineering tool does not generate POCOs as partials

Tags: entity-framework-core

Entity Framework 7 reverse engineering tool does not generate the POCOs as partials. Is there a specific reason for that?

Before EF7 we used to get partial classes so I could extend the functionality of POCOs. I was using partial classes to map the **Id** property to the Primary key property as shown below;

```
public partial class User: EntityBase
{
    public override int Id
    {
        get { return UserId; }
        set { UserId= value; }
    }
}
```

How can I do that in EF7?
Thank you.

Comment: It's a bug; they should be partial. I've filed issue [#3428](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3428).

Comment: Thank you Brice, I wasn't sure that's why I didn't want to fill a case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just an oversight. An Entity Framework bug was raised on this (see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3428). It was fixed today (Oct 16, 2015) - and will be in tonight's nightly build.

As a workaround the `scaffold-templates` approach mentioned above should work for now.

Or you are also free to just manually search and replace to add the word `partial` into any POCO class once it has been generated (though it would get overwritten every time you generated them again).

Answer (score 0):

dnx ef dbcontext **scaffold-templates**  EntityFramework.SqlServer

scaffold-templates command can be used to generate the **EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design.DbContextTemplate.cshtml** and **EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design.EntityTypeTemplate.cshtml** template files in the project directory to be used during scaffolding.

EntityTypeTemplate customization example to add partial class support:

```
....
....
@:namespace @Model.Namespace
@:{
@:    public partial class @Model.EntityType.Name
@:    {...
....
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using 6.1.3 and models are generated as partials.